# Printing each digit of a number using a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

I have an assignment where I have to print each digit while using a for loop and I am very confused. I know that the code I have written is VERY wrong for many reasons, but I'm having a lot of trouble piecing together the various skills we have been learning. How can I fix my code so that `365` is printed as `3 6 5`?

```java
class Main {
    method1(365);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    String number = String.valueOf(num);

    public int method1(int num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
            int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);
            System.out.print("digit: " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-order your code in correct syntax and order to make it work correctly,

1. call the `method1(365)` inside the main method
2. you have to make the `method1(365)` method static to be accessible as class method.
3. After converting int number to String then access each character of digit by `charAt`
4. you can use `int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);` to convert the character to a digit by base of 10 or simpley use `int j = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i));` which will be default on base of 10.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method1(365);
}

public static void method1(int num) {
    String number = String.valueOf(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);
     // int j = Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i));
        System.out.print("digit:" + j + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Michael I changed the code in correct syntax in Java.

Comment: Thanks, its better now

Answer (score 2):

Since *Java 9* you can use [`codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePoints--) method:

```java
int number = 365;
String.valueOf(number)
        // IntStream
        .codePoints()
        // Stream<String>
        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
        // print in a column
        .forEach(j -> System.out.println("digit: " + j));
```

Output:

```
digit: 3
digit: 6
digit: 5
```

---

<sup>See also: [Converting Int value to List of Integer digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66681988/15402945)</sup>